# Can python subscribe nodelet topic?

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, rostopic, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in ROS and I understand that nodelet is using ROS c++ interface.

Currently, I am using a library which can publish nodelet topic.
Should I have to write `subscriber`  in c++ or it's OK using python `subscriber`?

From my testing, I wrote a python script to sub nodelet topic which worked as well as normal node topic. But I am not sure whether `subscriber` is getting data from nodelet or normal node.

Thanks for helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289385/can-python-subscribe-nodelet-topic?/) by [marshalshiaug](https://answers.ros.org/users/34778/marshalshiaug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topics published by nodelets are no different from regular topics, apart from the fact that other nodelets hosted by the same nodelet manager can use shared memory to avoid (de)serialisation.

Regular nodes (ie: other processes) cannot, and will thus use the regular TCP/IP (or UDP) based transports to receive the messages (this is irrespective of the programming language: it's more about whether the subscribing node(let) shares an address space with the publisher).

If you desire/require zero-copy pub-sub, writing a nodelet in C++ will be required.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marshalshiaug](https://answers.ros.org/users/34778/marshalshiaug/) on 2018-04-23**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for your answer.  It's clear.